# k&r exercise 2-6 "setbits"

Tags: c, binary, kernighan-and-ritchie

I've seen the answer here: http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_2:Exercise_6

and i've tested the first, but in this part:

```
x = 29638;
y = 999;
p = 10;
n = 8;

return (x & ((~0 << (p + 1)) | (~(~0 << (p + 1 - n)))))
```

in a paper it give to me a 6, but in the program it return 28678...

in this part:

```
 111001111000110
&000100000000111
```

in the result, the left-most three bits has to be 1's like in `x` but the bitwise operator `&` says:

> The output of bitwise AND is 1 if the corresponding bits of all operands is 1. If either bit of an operand is 0, the result of corresponding bit is evaluated to 0.

so why it returns the number with thats 3 bits in 1?

Comment: When I run this, the right-hand side of the `&` operator evaluates to `0xf807` instead of `0x0807`. I believe this is the result of sign extension.

Comment: No wait it isn't sign extension, it's just that `~0 << 11` = `0xf000` and OR-ing with 7 doesn't get rid of those high-bit 1's. What was supposed to happen with `y`?

Comment: look in the link, there's the full program, i just cut this part cause is where i've the problem

Answer (score 3):

Here we go, one step at a time (using 16-bit numbers).  We start with:

```
(x & ((~0 << (p + 1)) | (~(~0 << (p + 1 - n)))))
```

Substituting in numbers (in decimal):

```
(29638 & ((~0 << (10 + 1)) | (~(~0 << (10 + 1 - 8)))))
```

Totalling up the bit shift amounts gives:

```
(29638 & ((~0 << 11) | (~(~0 << 3))))
```

Rewriting numbers as binary and applying the `~0`s...

```
(0111001111000110 & ((1111111111111111 << 1011) | (~(1111111111111111 << 0011))))
```

After performing the shifts we get:

```
(0111001111000110 & (1111100000000000 | (~ 1111111111111000)))
```

Applying the other bitwise-NOT (`~`):

```
(0111001111000110 & (1111100000000000 | 0000000000000111))
```

And the bitwise-OR (`|`):

```
0111001111000110 & 1111100000000111
```

And finally the bitwise-AND (`&`):

```
0111000000000110
```

So we then have binary `0111000000000110`, which is `2 + 4 + 4096 + 8192 + 16384`, which is `28678`.

Comment: so ~0 is the same amount of bits in x in 1's? when i read in the book "~0 is all the bits in 1, moving n bits to the left with ~0<<n" i understood something like: ~(~0<<3) = ~(1<<3) = ~1000 = 0111...

Comment: @cristch `0` is all bits zero... and bitwise NOT (`~`) flips each bit to its opposite, changing all those zeros to ones.  So `~0` gives all 1's.  With 8-bits, `~(~0<<3)` = `~(~00000000 << 3)` = `~(11111111 << 3)` = `~11111000` = `00000111`

Comment: so i have to use a template of 8 / 16 / 32 bits right? i didn't understand that part so i just when i'm doing the operation, i've added 0's in the left side of the lower bits number to match the bigger, i.e. i've done this: 110110 & 101 in this case, 110110 has 6 so i added 3 0's to 101, like this: 110110 & 000101... i'm learning all this without a base, so there are so much things that i don't know...

Comment: @cristch I'm only specify "8-bit", "16-bit", etc. because that's how many I'm showing... `0` will always have *all* bits set to 0, however many that is for `int` (as it's an `int` literal), and `~0` will have all bits set to 1, however many that is for `int`.